# Struct values changing on pthread create

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I'm having difficulty understanding why my struct data is being changed upon calling pthread_create. If the code from func1 is put in main, it works fine, which makes me think something is occurring in the pthread_create function with the tid array. Thanks.

Struct:

```
typedef struct {
  char * fileName;
  char outputPath[1000];
  char outputFileName[1000];
  int fileSize;
} FileInfo;
```

Main:

```
...
pthread_t tid[100];
int * tidSize = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*tidSize=0;
func1(tid, tidSize);
int i;

for(i=0;i<*tidSize;i++){
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL;
}
```

func1:

```
void folderFound(pthread_t tid[], int * tidSize){
...
DIR * dir = opendir(".");
struct dirent * file1;
while(file1 = readdir( dir ) ) != NULL):
  (*tidSize)++;
  FileInfo * fileInfoThread = (FileInfo *)malloc(sizeof(FileInfo));
  fileInfoThread->fileName = file1->d_name;
  struct stat stInput;
  stat(file1->d_name, &stInput);
  fileInfoThread->fileSize=stInput.st_size;
  strcat(fileInfoThread->outputFileName,file1->d_name);
  strcat(fileInfoThread->outputPath,fileInfoThread->outputFileName);
  //    ==============================
  printf("%s\n",fileInfoThread->outputPath); 
  printf("%s\n",fileInfoThread->fileName);
  printf("%d\n",fileInfoThread->fileSize);
  //    ==============================  THESE ALL PRINT CORRECTLY
  int rc = pthread_create(&tid[*tidSize-1], NULL, fileThread, fileInfoThread);
```

fileThread:

```
void *fileThread(void * arg){
 FileInfo * file = (FileInfo *)(arg);
 // =======================================
  printf("%s\n",file->outputPath);
  printf("%s\n",file->fileName);
  printf("%d\n",file->fileSize);
 // ======================================= DATA IS CORRUPT/MODIFIED HERE
  free(arg);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

Comment: Please post real code that reproduces your problem. e.g. your `*tidSize` is uninitialized in your pseudo-C-python example.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed some of the pseudo code to reflect my real code.

Comment: `fileInfoThread->fileName = file1->d_name;` is a bug, `d_name` doesn't have the right lifetime. You need to copy it.

Comment: this line: 'fileInfoThread->fileName = file1->d_name;' is only moving a pointer, which is not what is wanted, suggest strcpy( fileInfoThread->fileName, file1->d_name);''

Comment: in C, the returned value from malloc() and family should not be cast.  the returned value from malloc() and family should be checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the use of strcat() is not correct because the destination field contains garbage, so the NUL byte where strcat will use as the destination address could be anywhere, including not even in the destination field.  This leads to undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.  better to use strncpy( ptrDestination, ptrSource, lenDestination );  the strcat functions are (probably) corrupting the heap.

Comment: Thanks guys, implemented the solutions for the three things mentioned and the data seems to be passing through correctly now.